# Show and hide not working as per expected using `ng-show`

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I am trying to `show` and `hide` a search field. for that, I am using a single function and passing the option. it only `show` the search field, but i am not able to hide it back.

what is wrong here?

here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.showSearch =  false;

    $scope.searchHandler = function ( option ) {

      $scope.showSearch = option;

    }

});
```

html :

```
 <a ng-href="" ng-click="searchHandler('true')">Show</a>

    <div>

      <span ng-show="showSearch">
         <input type="text" name="quickSearch" id="quickSearch" value="Search" />
      </span>



    </div>

    <a ng-href="" ng-click="searchHandler('false')">Hide</a>//not working
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/a33YIKuX30M6Qr0ivttI?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give false not 'false' to the showSearch function
Show

```
<div>

  <span ng-show="showSearch">
     <input type="text" name="quickSearch" id="quickSearch" value="Search" />
  </span>



</div>

<a ng-href="" ng-click="searchHandler(false)">Hide</a>
```

Comment: the same thing for true

Comment: Yes, works. since the `true` value worked for me. so i thought the issue is not because of Boolean.

Comment: The string "false" is truthy.  The string "true" is also truthy.

Answer (score 1):

remove the single quotes around the 'false' in your searchHandler('false') call.

i.e.

you currently have: ng-click="searchHandler('false')"

change this to: ng-click="searchHandler(false)"

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it a boolean value rather than a string, so all you need to do it take out the quotation marks

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="searchHandler(false)">Hide</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quote character. Should be `searchHandler(false)` and `searchHandler(true)`

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler , can remove the function completely and just toggle the boolean:

```
<a ng-click="showSearch = !showSearch">Hide</a>
```

OR

```
<a ng-click="showSearch = false">Hide</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing single quotes should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');      </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.5"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<a ng-href="" ng-click="searchHandler('true')">Show</a>

<div>

  <span ng-show="showSearch">
     <input type="text" name="quickSearch" id="quickSearch" value="Search" />
  </span>



</div>

<a ng-href="" ng-click="searchHandler(false)">Hide</a>

</body>

</html>
```